# How to trigger the procedure for the sql database in system files

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that holds a bunch of values for an order, I can do basic calculations on it until I get to a percentage. Right now I have my query as follows

```
declare @MyNumber decimal
set @MyNumber = (select SalesTax from [OrderHeader] where OrderHeaderID = 20)

select 
    sum(o.MaterialPrice) as "MatPrice",
    sum(o.LaborPrice) as "LaborPrice",
    sum(o.MaterialCost) as "MaterialCost",
    sum(isnull(o.MaterialPrice,0)) - sum(isnull(o.MaterialCost,0)) - sum(isnull(o.LaborPrice,0)) * @MyNumber as "RESULT"
from [OrderDetail] o
inner join [OrderHeader] oh on oh.OrderHeaderID = o.OrderHeaderID
where o.OrderHeaderID = 20
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here.

Comment: This post does not include a `?` mark. Is there a question?

Comment: for my classmates on tomorow ,they will understand it. I am sorry to steal your time.

Answer (score -2):

**PLEASE CHANGE AT LEAST NAZOV**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `nazov` BEFORE UPDATE
ON test
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SET NEW.OLD_TEXT=OLD.TEXT;
END $$
DELIMITER;
```